# How to replace strings only in the string and numbers combination between double quotation Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to replace 「g」 with 「k」 in some article :

```
this is "g1"..., and  "g2" is......, last "g1034" shows that...
```

the end result will be

```
this is "k1"..., and  "k2" is......, last "k1034" shows that...
```

I'm using the following regex to find the pattern :

```
"([^"]*)"
```

but fail to replace with success.

How can I do a replacement? thx in advance

Comment: Maybe enough to just [replace `"g(?=\d)` with `"k`](https://regex101.com/r/2N3GZF/1) depends on input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use

```
"\Kg(?=\d+")
```

- `"` Match `"`
- `\Kg` Forget what is currenly matched using `\K`, then match `g`
- `(?=\d+")` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is 1+ digits and `"`

And replace with `k`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9xgVCl/1)

---

Another option could be using capturing groups

```
(")g(\d+")
```

In the replacement use the 2 groups

```
$1k$2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XjYeud/1)

**Note** that if you do not want to match only digits, you could use `[^"]+` instead of `\d+` to match at least 1 char after `g` or use `*` to match 0 or more chars after `g`